# Calculating the distance between two latitude and longitude points in android

Tags: android, google-maps

### How can i find the distance between `two` `latitude` & `longitude` points

---

For one of the latitude & longitude points i have it in database & another one i want to use current position of the mobile

**Which one should i need to use them among below:**:

- android location provider
- Google API
- Mathematical Calculation

**note**:: Any demo code sample will be useful